# Logging on serial debug port in c++

Tags: c++, linux, console

I want to write Logs on 'ttyS0' (the default debugging port on Linux) in my c++ application for debugging purposes, what should I do in my application to write Logs on this port instead of printing them with std::cout?

Answer (score 1):

You can open this device as a regular output file.

Of course, you need privileges in order to use this device (`sudo` ...)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int
main()
{
  std::ofstream log_stream{"/dev/ttyS0"};
  if(!log_stream)
  {
    std::cerr << "cannot open log stream\n";
  }
  else
  {
    for(auto i=0; i<5; ++i)
    {
      log_stream << "This is message number " << i << '\n';
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Compile with:

```sh
g++ -std=c++17 -o prog_cpp prog_cpp.cpp \
    -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wno-sign-conversion \
    -g -O0 -UNDEBUG -fsanitize=address,undefined
```

Comment: thank you for your response, I think in the linux the Debug port is always open to write data on that serial port, and I think I can't open that port.
maybe there is a function in c++ to call, to write on debug port? like 'printk' function in kernel module.

Comment: You can add yourself to the dialout group so you don't need sudo.